# Grant permissions to SQL Server user to view all entries in sys.objects

Tags: sql-server

How can I grant permissions for a user to view all entries in

```
sys.database_permissions
sys.objects
```

Example queries:

```
select name, object_id 
from sys.objects

select major_id 
from sys.database_permissions 
where major_id >= 0
```

Right now, the results differ between normal SQL Server user and sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

You should grant `VIEW DEFINITION` at database level:

```
use YourDB;
go

grant view definition to YourUser;
```